# Native iPhone audio format

Tags: iphone, audio

I've currently got my output audio on the iPhone setup as this :

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat;

audioFormat.mSampleRate = 48000;

audioFormat.mFormatID   = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;

audioFormat.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;

audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;

audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;

audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16;

audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket = 4;

audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame = 4;
```

However, when I examine my performance figures through shark I am seeing functions such as : 
`SRC_Convert_table_i32_scalar_stereo`

take a fair chunk of time.

This made me think - what is the ideal and suggested output format for the iPhone? The one that requires as little work for the device to play.

Comment: How are you using Shark with the iPhone? Are you sure you're not profiling the simulator? RF

Comment: No, I'm profiling the device.

Here is a page that tells you how to setup shark to profile iPhones : https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/SharkUserGuide/SelectingExecutiontoSampleorTrace/chapter_6_section_9.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Shark does work with the iPhone.  You can enable iPhone profiling by selecting "Sampling > Network/iPhone Profiling..." in the menu.

Definitely try using a 44100 Hz sampling rate.  With 48000 I see the same function that you posted appearing in the callstacks -- no such function shows up when using 44100.  The canonical audio format for Audio Units on the iPhone is non-interleaved 8.24 linear PCM:

```
streamFormat.mFormatID         = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
streamFormat.mFormatFlags      = 
                  kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger
                | kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian
                | kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved
                | (24 << kLinearPCMFormatFlagsSampleFractionShift);
streamFormat.mSampleRate       = mixing_rate;
streamFormat.mBitsPerChannel   = 32;
streamFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;
streamFormat.mFramesPerPacket  = 1;
streamFormat.mBytesPerFrame    = ( streamFormat.mBitsPerChannel / 8 );
streamFormat.mBytesPerPacket   = streamFormat.mBytesPerFrame *
                                 streamFormat.mFramesPerPacket;
```

Answer (score 3):

From [iphone dev centre](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AudioandVideoTechnologies/chapter_9_section_2.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH19-SW32) (requires login) the hardware suppoorted codecs are

> **iPhone Audio Hardware Codecs**
>
> iPhone OS applications can use a wide
>   range of audio data formats, as
>   described in the next section. Some of
>   these formats use software-based
>   encoding and decoding. You can
>   simultaneously play multiple sounds in
>   these formats. Moreover, your
>   application and a background
>   application (notably, the iPod
>   application) can simultaneously play
>   sounds in these formats.
>
> Other iPhone OS audio formats employ a
>   hardware codec for playback. These
>   formats are:
>
> - AAC
> - ALAC (Apple Lossless)
> - MP3

Comment: I'm less interested in the different formats that the iphone is able to play, more what the base format of the output is. That way I can match my output type, and it will require less cycles for the iPhone to convert.

Comment: I would have assumed that by using a hardware codec you would use fewer cpu cycles... I might be wrong, try out and tell us how it goes

Answer (score 1):

48000 is a weird format for audio in general. While it's marginally (and imperceptibly) better than CD standard 44.1Khz it's not worth the size.

Is there any compelling reason in your app to use high quality stereo sound? In other words is the app likely to be played on speakers or good headphones?

LinearPCM format is hardware native so it should be optimal. (No decompression to fiddle with.) So that call may be a downsample to 44.1Khz.