# Most efficient way to format a large amount of audio files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am currently developing an app that will contain large amounts of audio, around 60-120 minutes. Most voice audio files. My question is really what is the best way to go about storing them. For example, one single large file, separate audio files, download-as-needed cache files.

Any suggestions on file format?

Comment: What kind is the audio content (music, voice, sounds)?

Comment: Almost 100% voice audio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the [audio formats decoded by iPhone hardware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/632787/477878) that should take the least power to play.

> Other iPhone OS audio formats employ a hardware codec for playback.
>   These formats are:
>
> - AAC
> - ALAC (Apple Lossless)
> - MP3

Whether to have the audio distributed with the app or separately would depend on the use. If you could reasonably expect the user to go through the material sequentially, you may want to allow the user to download part by part or stream the audio to let them conserve space on their device, while if the audio is more random access, you'd probably want it all on the device.

Comment: What you said totally makes sense. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

Several apps, including Apple's own, appear to use the open source speex codec for compressed voice-quality audio, even though this seems not to be supported by the hardware or any public API.

Answer (score 1):

As Joachim suggested you can choose from AAC/ALAC/MP3 audio formats. What I'd propose now is to also consider the issue from user experience point of view:

1. Convert all your audio to chosen format with quality options that
   satisfy you and your potential users.
2. Next, calculate the size of all your files and ask yourself a questions:
   "are X megabytes too much to bundle for my kind of app?" and
   "will that big/small app bundle encourage users to download my app?".
3. Optionally play a bit with quality options to shrink files (iterate).
4. In the next step, decide (based on you app characteristics) whether to bundle all files. For example a game is expected to have all files in place and can be big (users accept that). If your app has e.g. podcasts only, then select the best one and bundle it - once user is hooked he can download the rest (let user trigger that), so files are stored on device.      Also provide user the info how much data they are about to download and warn them if file is reasonably big and they're not on Wi-Fi; or introduce the option to download only on Wi-Fi.

I hope that sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

For music, the following approach would be much different.

Since it's just voice, you can reduce the sample rate significantly in the majority of cases. Try [8kHz…20kHz].

In case they are multichannel - Mono should be fine for voice.

Once that's been done, I'd recommend AAC for size and quality balance.

Do some listening tests on your devices. Tweak settings if needed. Then batch process/convert them all. That can reduce your sizes by ten or more if the sources are 16/44.1.

Unless they files are very small (e.g. seconds each) or you have to open and read many of them quickly, I wouldn't bother with the huge file. A few MB is a good size for many cases.