# How to reduce the size of my iPhone application which has more high quality audio files?

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios4, audio-streaming

I am developing application related to meditation.
In that there is lots of high quality .mp3 files, that's why application size increases much more nearer to 2GB. I have searched for compression but i can't found it for audio files, but xcode supports only for .png file.

If anyone know anything about it then please suggest me.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you compress them before you deploy the application? If so, try something like [Lame MP3 encoder](http://lame.sourceforge.net/). Also, what bitrate and compression was used to create the .mp3 files in the first place?

Comment: .png is a image file format.  Also, you can try to convert them to lower quality, or maybe zip up the mp3's for download and then unzip them on the device.

Comment: What happens if you just use gzip or bzip or other common utility? However, even if you compress it for downloading, you still have to uncompress it to use it.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931039/most-efficient-way-to-format-a-large-amount-of-audio-files/8932907#8932907

Answer (score 0):

MP3 is lossy compression.  If you are willing to accept lossy files, MP3 is much better compression than you will get with a regular data compression algorithm, such as gzip.

What I would suggest would be getting the original files and re-compressing with AAC, down to a bitrate that makes the size of your application acceptable.  AAC sounds better at lower bitrates, and compressing from the original means you won't have any artifacts from the already lossy-compressed MP3 files.